# Batch file for changing IP address not working in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, ip, batch-file

I have used batch files for years on XP and Windows 7 to change the IP settings on my Local Area Connection. For example:

```
netsh interface ip set address name = "Local Area Connection" source = static addr = 192.168.255.126 mask = 255.255.255.0 gateway = 192.168.255.129 gwmetric = 1
```

I have recently changed to Windows 8 Pro and cannot get these batch files to work. I have run them as administrator, checked the naming of my LAN connection etc. Can anyone help me get these working as I have to change the IP address on my LAN connection up to 30 times a day which can get tiresome if I have to do it manually each time.

Comment: What happens when you try it? Do you get any error messages? Is your network interface still named "Local Area Connection"?

Answer (score 1):

Take another look at the "name" parameter.  I have a couple of batch files to change between using statically designated DNS servers (my preferred method!) and getting the DNS server via DHCP (otherwise you usually can't connect at Starbucks/McDonalds, etc.)

My batch files worked in XP, Vista, and 7, but when I got a laptop with 8 they stopped working.  It turned out that after years of naming the network connections "Local Area Connection", "Local Area Connection 2", etc., Microsoft finally gave in and called them "Ethernet" and "Wi-Fi".

(You've always been able to rename them, but now for the first time their names default to something logical...)

Comment: Hi, I've checked and double checked the name of the Ethernet connection and even renamed, but still can't get the batch file to work. I have also tried renaming the port on the script to 'Ethernet' and it makes no difference.

Comment: @MartinBagshaw - Well, it works for me - both as a batch file and just from the command line - but, as I said, not until I changed the "name" parameter to "Ethernet".  I'm using Win8 64-bit Home Premium (don't laugh, it came with the laptop!); perhaps it's been nerfed in Pro, but I find that hard to believe...